# Suggest regular expression for complex password defintion

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to meet password complexity definition. I don't have much experience on regular expression so it would be appreciated if someone can design it for me with explanation.

The password must contain at least 3 types of characters out of four options (one upper case, one lower case, number, special character) and there should not be the same consecutive character more than twice. For example, "Sahash11" is correct, but "Sahash111" is incorrect.

Comment: I would say that it is impossible to create a regular expression fulfilling your constraints. And even if it was possible, the question remains why do it? Instead, separate your different conditions to different expressions and do a logical AND between them.

Comment: It will be a super long regex.A program would be much better

Comment: Thank you Dov for the reply! but since i dont want to force all four conditions( one upper case , one lower case, one number , one special character) so how can i achieve this using logical AND. I only need to make sure that user enters three type of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to do it with an engine that supports conditionals.
Could easily be, for example 14 out of 30. Simply add more constructs
to the alternation, then set the quantifier to how many you require.

Example `(?:.*?(?:this|that|a|b|c|9)){3}` requires 3 of 6.
(Note that a conditional must be inserted into each alternation pertinent to the group)

**Late Addition Note**
You can always set a range in the quantifier
Example from above `(?:.*?(?:this|that|a|b|c|9)){3,6}`  requires 3 of 6.
Doing this allows some useful post match analyses.

For example, if you want to test the strength of the password.
After the match you could check each capture group for a match, then
increment a strength counter.

Like:

```
int strength = 0;
for (int i=1; i<=6; i++)
if ( match[i].success )
     strength++;
```

---

```
 #  ^(?!.*?(.)\1\1)(?:.*?(?>((?(2)(?!))[A-Z]+)|((?(3)(?!))[a-z]+)|((?(4)(?!))[0-9]+)|((?(5)(?!))[!@#$%^&*()\[\]_+}{?><,./":;'-]+))){3}.*$

 (?m)                        # Multi-line modifier (remove if a single line string
 ^                           # Beginning of string
 (?!                         # Not 3 consecutive same char's
      .*? 
      ( . )                       # (1)
      \1 \1 
 )
 (?:
      .*?     
      (?>                         # Atomic group
           (                           # (2 start), Upper case
                (?(2)                       # Exclude from matching again
                     (?!)
                )
                [A-Z]+ 
           )                           # (2 end)
        |  (                           # (3 start), Lower case
                (?(3)                       # Exclude from matching again
                     (?!)
                )
                [a-z]+ 
           )                           # (3 end)
        |  (                           # (4 start), Number
                (?(4)                       # Exclude from matching again
                     (?!)
                )
                [0-9]+ 
           )                           # (4 end)
        |  (                           # (5 start), Special char's (add to the class)
                (?(5)                       # Exclude from matching again
                     (?!)
                )
                [!@#$%^&*()\[\]_+}{?><,./":;'-]+ 
           )                           # (5 end)
      )
 ){3}                        # Match 3 out of 4
 .* 
 $                           # End of string
```